# How can I programmatically determine which files are currently open in evince?

Tags: command-line, evince

I have opened a PDF file with the document viewer from the GUI. Is there any way to get the path of this file in a terminal/script?

Comment: file->properties will show you the current path of the opened file.

Comment: I want to have that in terminal and not using mouse

Comment: If you open file in terminal, you already now file location. Or we do not understand each other?

Comment: no open file not from terminal and after that track PDF from terminal and so say the file location about track I should say some thing like process like ps command

Comment: Your question don't reflect what you are saying in the comments, please clarify your question to reflect what you want exactly.

Comment: @Jobin I edited.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TLDR:**

```
for ip in $(pgrep -x evince); do lsof -F +p $ip|grep -i '^n.*\.pdf$'|sed s/^n//g; done
```

**Explanation:**

`Document Viewer` is the friendly name for the program `/usr/bin/evince`. So first we need to find the process ID (PID) of `evince`:

```
$ pgrep -x evince
22291
```

To list all files opened by this PID we will use the `lsof` command (note that we'll need to repeat this for every PID in case we have more than one instance of evince running)

```
$ lsof -F +p 22291
some other files opened
.
.
.
n/home/c0rp/File.pdf
```

Next we'll grep only for pdfs and discard the irrelevant n at start of line:

```
$ lsof -Fn +p 22291 | grep -i '^n.*\.pdf$' | sed s/^n//g
/home/c0rp/File.pdf
```

Finally to combine everything in one bash line:

```
for ip in $(pgrep -x evince); do lsof -F +p $ip|grep -i '^n.*\.pdf$'|sed s/^n//g; done
```

This one-liner was inspired from the answer of terdon which is also very interesting in the way it solves the same problem.

---

If you are interested in what *n* in `lsof -Fn` is for, here is quote from `man lsof` about the `-F` option:

```
OUTPUT FOR OTHER PROGRAMS
       When the -F option is specified, lsof produces output that is  suitable
       for  processing by another program - e.g, an awk or Perl script, or a C
       program. 
...
...
       These  are  the  fields  that  lsof will produce.  The single character
       listed first is the field identifier.
...
...
            n    file name, comment, Internet address
...
...
```

so `-Fn`, is saying show me `file name, comment, Internet address`

Comment: what a nice answers

Answer (score 6):

Another approach would be something like

```
$ for ip in $(pgrep -x evince); do lsof -F +p $ip  | grep -oP '^n\K.*\.pdf$'; done
/home/terdon/file1.pdf
/home/terdon/file2.pdf
```

#### Explanation

In general, whenever you want to search fro a process, `pgrep` is better than `ps -ef | grep process` since the latter will also match the `grep` process itself. For example:

```
$ ps -ef | grep emacs
terdon    6647  6424 23 16:26 pts/14   00:00:02 emacs
terdon    6813  6424  0 16:26 pts/14   00:00:00 grep --color emacs
$ pgrep emacs
6647
```

The `-x` option returns only processes whose entire name matches the string passed. This is needed because `evince` also starts a daemon (`evinced`) and that will also be matched without the `-x` (the `-l` is to print the name as well as the PID):

```
$ pgrep -l evince
4606 evince
4611 evinced
4613 evince
$ pgrep -lx evince
4606 evince
4613 evince
```

So, the for loop will run `lsof` on each of the PIDs returned by `pgrep`. These are then passed through `grep`. The `-o` option means "print only the matched portion of the line"  and the `-P` activates Perl Compatible Regular Expressions which lets us use `\K`. In PCREs, `\K` means "discard everything matched before the `\K  ". In other words, since I am using`-o`, it will match lines beginning with`n`and ending with`.pdf`but it will not print the matched`n`. The result is that only the file's name is printed.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify even the filename of the pdf  opened through Document Viewer. This below command will display the paths of all the pdf files opened through Document Viewer.`evince` is the actual command to open Document Viewer via terminal.

```
ps -ef | grep evince | sed -n '/.*\.pdf/p' | sed 's/.*evince \(.*\)$/\1/g'
```

**Example:**

```
$ ps -ef | grep evince | sed -n '/.*\.pdf/p' | sed 's/.*evince \(.*\)$/\1/g'
/media/avinash/C68C57908C5779BF/pdf/PHP/PHP-Manual.pdf
/media/avinash/C68C57908C5779BF/pdf/python.pdf
```

But all the credit goes to [@Corp](https://askubuntu.com/users/164083/c0rp).